# What's included in Starcraft II Starter Kit?

Tags: starcraft-2

Here in the phillipines, there's a starcraft 2 starter kit that's quite  a bit cheaper than the full game (180 vs 3500 pesos). I'm wondering what's included in the package. I know that it needs prepaid cards in order to access the multiplayer, but what about the campaign and the skirmish modes? Can i play using the guest mode, or the offline mode?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the following tidbit on the [Team Liquid forums](http://www.teamliquid.net/forum/viewmessage.php?topic_id=140442):

> **The DVD starter kit will contain a 7-day pass along with a guide to creating a Battle.net account and installing the client.**

It's part of a larger press release that is quoted in that post:

> IRVINE, Calif. – Blizzard Entertainment, Inc. today announced that a range of prepaid game card options for the English version of its record-breaking real-time strategy game StarCraft® II: Wings of Liberty™ will be available to players in Hong Kong/Macau, Indonesia, Malaysia, the Philippines, Singapore, and Thailand beginning 18 November, 2010.
>
> StarCraft II: Wings of Liberty game cards provide an additional, flexible payment option alongside the existing boxed version of StarCraft II, which includes unlimited access for the life of the game. They are available in 3-day, 7-day, and 30-day pass versions, and can be used on the Southeast Asian Battle.net® server for StarCraft II single-player and multiplayer play. A DVD starter kit will also be available, allowing players to install the game client quickly and conveniently without the need to download it. The DVD starter kit will contain a 7-day pass along with a guide to creating a Battle.net account and installing the client. Suggested retail prices for the game cards and starter kit in each region are listed below:
>   Region 3-day pass 7-day pass 30-day pass DVD Starter Kit With 7-day Pass
>   Hong Kong/Macau 8 HKD 16 HKD 55 HKD 30 HKD
>   Indonesia 10,000 IDR 20,000 IDR 70,000 IDR 35,000 IDR
>   Malaysia 3.50 MYR 7 MYR 25 MYR 12 MYR
>   Philippines 50 PHP 100 PHP 350 PHP 170 PHP
>   Singapore 1.50 SGD 3 SGD 10.50 SGD 5 SGD
>   Thailand 35 THB 70 THB 250 THB 120 THB
>
> The prepaid game cards and DVD starter kit will be distributed across Southeast Asia in select Internet gaming cafes, convenience stores, and gaming retail shops. For more information about the StarCraft II: Wings of Liberty passes and where to buy them, visit the info page at http://blizzard.iahgames.com.

Comment: So it's the full game? With the whole campaign, skirmish mode, etc.? Do you think I can play it offline?

Comment: Only for 7 days and IIRC also online. After 7 days you then have to buy a full version (maybe a key only is sufficient).